# Where can I publish my Windows Indie game?

Tags: xna, xbox360

I've just finished an XNA game for the Windows Phone 7 and XBLIG.  At the moment, the game is a 'lite' version, so is free, but the next version will have a small price-tag.

I also did a Windows version.  Where's the best place to publish it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Post it everywhere you can; Steam, Desura... Head over to the Business section of http://tigsource.com forum. Send to this page too to also publish it on cover. Send also to http://indiegames.com/index.html

It is a good way to advertise.

Answer (score 6):

The most thriving indie marketplace on Windows right now has got to be Steam. Not every successful indie game is there, bu most indie games do very well there compared to independently.

Comment: Steam is also cool for the Indie package offers

Comment: @DeadMG The only successful indie game I can think of that isn't there is Minecraft (and that's a special case). What else are you thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

I think steam is your best bet; I've seen a lot of XNA games doing fairly well there lately. Read through the following page and if you're still interested, send Valve an email.

http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/FAQ.php

Answer (score 2):

Obviously Steam is the best place to be, if you can get in.

If not, take a look at IndieCity - http://www.indiecity.com - another distribution platform for indie PC games, which hasn't yet launched but seems to be getting closer - maybe you can get your game on it in time for it's launch?

Comment: +1 for mentioning Indiecity. It looks very promising to me.